RabbitMQ queue is not created on spring startup
Please help me to solve issues with Spring rabbitmq queue creation. I've searched every stakcoverflow posted questions, but non seems to work.
I am using Spring 2.7.18. My rabbit configuration class:
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    private final RabbitProperties rabbitProperties;

    public RabbitConfiguration(RabbitProperties rabbitProperties) {
        this.rabbitProperties = rabbitProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(createQueue());
        return amqpAdmin;
    }

    @Bean
    public Declarables queues() {
        return new Declarables(createQueue());
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue createQueue() {  
        return new Queue("queueName", true, false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
}

application.properties
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=xxx
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=xxx
spring.rabbitmq.username=xxx
spring.rabbitmq.password=xxx
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm=TLSv1.2

I see that my application created connection.
If I have queue created via Rabbit admin panel I can send messages to the rabbit.
However, then I delete the queue via admin panel it's not created.
I am thinking that queue should be created either during app start up or either sending a message to the rabbit. Am I wrong? :(
I use service only to send messages via rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()
Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#373052b5:0/SimpleConnection@8ca3b65 [delegate=amqp://xxx@xxxx:xxx/vhost, localPort= xxxx]


Any chances you can share that simple project with us, so we can investigate it? I don't see anything suspicious (unless that manual   amqpAdmin.declareQueue(createQueue());). This RabbitAdmin creates RabbitMQ objects from those beans on connection established. So, all should be good. Unless you see something else in logs.

Thats the case nothing in logs. Maybe there are differences connecting via 5671 port instead 5672?

OK. So, for Spring Boot and whatever you show so far, you don't need amqpAdmin, rabbitTemplate and queues beans. First two are auto-configured for us. The Declarables is for batch. I believe you are going to use that queueName some way in your application. So, this createQueue still must be there to have RabbitMQ object created on the broker on connection establishment.

I tired removing everything and leaving with Bean Queue, same story nothing happens. I tried adding bindings, exchange, admin, connectionFactory manually. Still nothing. I thought maybe a dependency issues, but I guess I would not be able to use convertAndSend as well then I have Queue created manually. So nothing makes sense. I even tried using old school rabbitChannel.basicPublish("", "queueName", PERSISTENT_JSON, eventString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); It works. Somehow spring don't want to work with me.

The basicPublish has nothing to do with queue creation on the broker. So, or we need a project from you to run on our side, or more concise explanation what is going on/

Oh gosh. Sorry wrong paste. In the older project it worked like this rabbitChannel.queueDeclare("queueName", durable, false, false, null);. I get it it's hard for me to make this project available. :(

Yeah. You don't need to share exactly that project, but you can go to https://start.spring.io/ and create a simple project which you would be able to share with us somewhere in GitHub.

Finally managed for it to work. Seems Queue bean is being ignored. But rabbitTemplate.execute(channel -> channel.queueDeclare("branch", true, false, false, null)); this way it works.
